# Condition on checkbox

Tags: c#

My questions is quite simple but i don't find any way to do it.

I have several checkboxs, I  want to run my void only if **2** of them or more are checked

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

      if (!checkbox1.Checked && !checkbox2.Checked && !checkbox3.Checked &&     !checkbox4.Checked && !checkbox5.Checked)
      {
       Messagebox.Show("Select 2 checkbox");
       return;
      }
       else
      {
       //some action
      }
}
```

is the trick I use to be sure one checkbox is checked.. But I want to do the same with 2 & more checkboxs.

Ps: I can't use  `private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged()` , I need to use my button1 event.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could indeed *count the number of checked checkboxes* like that:

```
int count = 0;
if (checkbox1.Checked) count += 1;
if (checkbox2.Checked) count += 1;
if (checkbox3.Checked) count += 1;
if (checkbox4.Checked) count += 1;

if (count < 2)
{
    Messagebox.Show("Select 2 checkbox");    
    return;
}
```

Or you could put all relevant checkboxes in an array and do this.

```
CheckBox[] checkboxes = new [] { checkbox1, checkbox2, checkbox3, checkbox4 };
if (checkboxes.Count(cb => cb.Checked) < 2)
{
    Messagebox.Show("Select 2 checkbox");    
    return;
}
```

The second version easily be extended for more checkboxes by simply adding them to the array.

---

If even *all* checkboxes on your form do count, you can use

```
if(Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Count(cb => cb.Checked) < 2)
{
    // ....
}
```

Comment: @ZoharPeled right, I somehow thought that there was no such `Count()` overload, but I just confused it with `Contains()`. (though I remember that `Where().Count()` should be faster than `Count()`, but I think it's not relevant here).

Comment: ...or put them in a container control to avoid that unrelated CheckBoxes on the form also count. Then you can use `CheckBoxContainer.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Count(cb=>cb.Checked)`